# how to draw line between buttons in android

Tags: java, android

i want to draw line between middle point of two buttons.i created that useing below code i check it in my android emulator it is working correctly.i put that apk to my phone but those  lines are not in correct position. 
how to position line between two middle points of two buttons?

it should be applicable for every android phones with different screen size

this is how i want to draw lines
![IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/1o7hj9.png[/IMG]
[![android emulator][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/586S1.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/586S1.png)

//activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffaa" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bx1y1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bx2y1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bx1y2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bx2y2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      DrawView drawView;

      Button bx1y1,bx2y1,bx1y2,bx2y2;
      RelativeLayout rl1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         bx1y1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bx1y1);
         bx2y1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bx2y1);
         bx1y2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bx1y2);
         bx2y2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bx2y2);
         rl1 =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl1);


         bx2y1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    drawline(1);
                }
            });

         bx1y2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    drawline(3);
                    drawline(6);
                }
            });

         bx2y2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    drawline(2);
                    drawline(4);

                    drawline(5);
                }
            });
        }
        protected void drawline(int linenum) {
            switch (linenum) {
            case 1://x start
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx1y1,bx2y1,18,18,18,18);
                  rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;
            case 2:
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx1y2,bx2y2,18,54,18,54);
                  rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;
            case 3:
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx1y1,bx1y2,18,18,18,54);
                  rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;
            case 4:
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx2y1,bx2y2,18,18,18,54);
                rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;
            case 5:
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx1y1,bx2y2,18,18,18,54);
                rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;
            case 6:
                drawView = new DrawView(MainActivity.this,bx2y1,bx1y2,18,18,18,54);
                rl1.addView(drawView);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
}
```

//DrawView

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    View startView;
    View endView;
    int sx,sy,ex,ey;

    public DrawView(Context context,View startView,View endView,int sx,int sy,int ex,int ey) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
        this.startView = startView;
        this.endView = endView;
        this.sx=sx;
        this.sy=sy;
        this.ex=ex;
        this.ey=ey;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawLine(startView.getX()+sx, startView.getY()+sy, endView.getX()+ex, endView.getY()+ey, paint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

This will create a horizontal line that is `2dp` high. Add this between your two buttons, with appropriate positioning in your `RelativeLayout`

The other option would be to use a shape drawable if you want a more customized line between the two buttons.

Comment: actually i want to draw line between middle points of two buttons how do i position it? it should be applicable for every android phone (different display size)

Comment: Look at the `FrameLayout`. See if that helps.